# Defining a shapeless replacer

Tags: scala, shapeless

I wonder how can I fix this Scala code using the Shapeless library so that it compiles:

```scala
object boo {

  import shapeless._

  sealed trait Bibby
  case class LittleBibby(i: Int) extends Bibby
  case class BigBibby(s: String) extends Bibby
  type Bibbies = LittleBibby :: BigBibby :: HNil

  val defaultBibbies: Bibbies = LittleBibby(1) :: BigBibby("beep") :: HNil

  def update(b: Bibby, bibbies: Bibbies) : Bibbies = bibbies.updatedElem(b)

  val demo: Bibbies = update(LittleBibby(3), defaultBibbies)

}
```

I get the following error message:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter replacer:shapeless.Replacer[boo.Bibbies,boo.Bibby,boo.Bibby]
def update(b: Bibby, bibbies: Bibbies) : Bibbies = bibbies.updatedElem(b)
```

I have tried to look through the shapeless source code in order to find a solution to create the missing implicit `Replacer`, but to no avail :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `shapeless.Replacer` information about actual element type should be available in compile time. There is no element of type `Bibby` in `Bibbies`, so there is nothing to replace.

You should use a generic type for `b`, and also you should add required `Replacer[Bibbies, B, B]` as implicit parameter like this:

```
def update[B <: Bibby](b: B, bibbies: Bibbies)(implicit r: Replacer[Bibbies, B, B]) =
  bibbies.updatedElem(b)

update(LittleBibby(3), defaultBibbies)
// LittleBibby(3) :: BigBibby(beep) :: HNil
```

Answer (score 1):

You *discarded* the information about whether the bibby is a little bibby or a big bibby:

```
def update(b: Bibby, bibbies: Bibbies) : Bibbies
```

I have no idea whether this will be enough, but I'd start by preserving the bibby type:

```
def update[T <: Bibby](b: T, bibbies: Bibbies) : Bibbies
```

You should then add an implicit `Replacer` parameter (as the error message asks for):

```
def update[T <: Bibby](b: T, bibbies: Bibbies)
                      (implicit ev: Replacer[Bibbies, T, T]): Bibbies
```

Comment: actually all required information is in the error message: `for parameter replacer:shapeless.Replacer[boo.Bibbies,boo.Bibby,boo.Bibby]`.

Comment: @senia Yes, but I only realized that when I reformatted the error message.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - This means that if I use update in concert with an actor's receive I need to something akin to (anyways):

    `def update : (Bibby ⇒ Bibbies) = {
      case lb: LittleBibby ⇒ update(lb, defaultBibbies)
      case bb: BigBibby    ⇒ update(bb, defaultBibbies)
    }`

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - Usecase would be something like:

    `def updated : ((Bibby, Bibbies) ⇒ Bibbies) = (b, bs) ⇒ b match {
      case lb: LittleBibby ⇒ update(lb, bs)
      case bb: BigBibby    ⇒ update(bb, bs)
    }`

I have some worker actors that are requested to do some work and each responds with an instance of `Bibby` - thus I start with `defaultBibbies` and by using `context.become` I can fire off requests and eventually build up a result of `Bibbies` that is handed off to the initiating master actor.

Comment: @ahjohannessen Pretty much. Actors erase type information, so they are at odds with strongly typed code, such as Shapeless, which relies on type that can be determined at compile time.